# working with powers in ocaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I am trying to write a recursive function that will return true if second number is power of first number. 
For example:
find_power 3 9 will return true
find_power 2 9 will return false because the power of 2 is 8 not 9

This is what I have tried but I need a recursive solution

```
let rec find_power first second = 
if (second mod first = 0)
return true
else
false ;;
```

Comment: You're on the wrong track - 6 is not a power of 2.

Comment: Note that `if cond then true else false` is a bad habit. Replace with: `cond`. Also you don't need the `return`.

Answer (score 3):

A recursive function has the following rough form

```
let rec myfun a b =
    if answer is obvious then
       obvious_answer
    else
        let (a', b') = smaller_example_of_same_problem a b in
        myfun a' b'
```

In your case, I'd say the answer is obvious if the second number is not a *multiple* of the first or if it's 1. That is essentially all your code is doing now, it's testing the obvious part. (Except you're not handling the 0th power, i.e., 1.)

So, you need to figure out how to make a smaller example of the same problem. You know (by hypothesis) that the second number *is* a multiple of the first one. And you know that `x * a` is a power of `a` if and only if `x` is a power of `a`. Since `x` is smaller than `x * a`, this is a smaller example of the same problem.

This approach doesn't work particularly well in some edge cases, like when the first number is 1 (since `x` is not smaller than `x * 1`). You can probably handle them separately.